# Density estimation for streams of Data

Tags: kernel-smoothing

What statistical methods out there that will estimate the probability density of data as it arrives temporally?

This is the situation I have:

I need to estimate the pdf of a multivariate dataset; however, new data arrives over time and as the data arrives the density estimation must update.

What I have been using so far is kernel estimations by storing all the data and computing a new kernel density estimation with every update of new data; however, I cannot keep up with the amount of data needed to be stored. Therefore, I need a method that will keep track of the overall pdf/density estimation then be able to update itself when new data arrives. This sort of sounds like it may need some sort of Bayesian method but I am not sure

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: You could store your data as counts in intervals, where the intervals are substantially narrower than the bandwith you are using for smoothing your kernel. Then you just need to remember as many numbers as there are intervals.

Comment: I have posted a somewhat related question (with bounty!) here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382260/temporal-generalization-of-graphs-density-vs-n-and-m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have become curious about the topic and performed a brief research. It appears that, generally, the **taxonomy** of approaches to *kernel density estimation (KDE)* for *data streams* consists of two large groups: *offline* and *online* approaches. The offline approaches include so called *CF-kernel* and *KD-kernel* methods, while the online approaches include *grid-based*, *sample-based* and *cluster-based* groups of methods. More details about this taxonomy as well as one of the methods (called *adaptive KDE*), can be found in [this research paper](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/fchen1/KAIS_LRKDE.pdf).

*M-Kernel* method is the core of the *cluster-based approach* to KDE for streaming data and is discussed in various research papers, for example in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.59.28) and [this](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~wli/publications/deosd.pdf). Finally, an interesting and novel method, implementing KDE for data streams, based on *self-organizing maps (SOM)*, has been proposed recently. It is called *SOMKE* and is described in [this research paper](http://egr.uri.edu/wp-uploads/he/somke-kernel-density-estimation.pdf). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had come across M-kernel before and was considering it for a long time.

Comment: @user2909415: You're very welcome. I'm glad that you liked my answer. Feel free to upvote. Now you have a wider range of options, not only M-kernel :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to store some samples of the data, you can also try [reservoir sampling.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) Basically, you can build one or more reservoirs of samples and run the usual kernel density estimation algorithms on top your samples. The challenge then becomes how to figure out the number of reservoirs and sample sizes, and what is the confidence interval on your estimates.